# Is it ever acceptable for REST API to return something other than JSON/XML?

Tags: json, xml, rest, http

I am currently trying to build a REST endpoint whereby an authenticated user can download a PDF. In researching the proper way to do this, I have mostly seen that JSON or XML are the proper response bodies to give. However, [this](http://rest.elkstein.org/search?updated-max=2008-02-12T20:00:00-08:00&max-results=4) site explains that the response can be something other than JSON as long as it's some human-readable document.

So, is it ever okay for a REST API to return application/pdf as the response type instead of application/json or application/xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely, a RESTful API can return whatever it wants. There is no constraint to be human-readable (although I think the linked article tries to argue exactly the opposite). Just think of the Web, which is REST-based, returning images, movies, sometimes even runnable code.

There are however *some* constraints. Any representation returned should be 'self-contained', meaning it has to has every piece of information necessary for the client to make sense of it. In this case, it would basically mean to just set the type 'application/pdf' properly on the response.